# .gitignore file in django

Tags: django, github, gitignore

i should do a push of my small project in django/redis and python on github but i noticed that after creating some users and doing the push, they are also saved on github. Reading on the internet I should create a gitignore file but I don't know what to write in it.
I should obviously save the migrations but not the data that has been entered in the database.
i found a file on gitignore.io but i am not sure if everything in it fits my case. do you have any tips or sites where i can check this?

Comment: What file was committed that created users? Here's a sample .gitignore file from [django-project-template](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-project-template/blob/master/.gitignore) and here's one from [djangowaves](https://djangowaves.com/tips-tricks/gitignore-for-a-django-project/).

Comment: Are you using SQLite as your database? The database file should probably be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have written .gitignore for one of my project built on Django and using Redis server for cache management. I hope it could help you to get idea of what you might need to add.

```
venv/
    .env
    __pycache__
    .vscode/
    static_cdn/
    media/*
    ### Python template
    # Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
    __pycache__/
    *.py[cod]
    *$py.class
    
    # C extensions
    *.so
    
    # Distribution / packaging
    .Python
    env/
    build/
    develop-eggs/
    dist/
    downloads/
    eggs/
    .eggs/
    lib/
    lib64/
    parts/
    sdist/
    var/
    *.egg-info/
    .installed.cfg
    *.egg
    
    # PyInstaller
    #  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
    #  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
    *.manifest
    *.spec
    
    # Installer logs
    pip-log.txt
    pip-delete-this-directory.txt
    
    # Unit test / coverage reports
    htmlcov/
    .tox/
    .coverage
    .coverage.*
    .cache
    nosetests.xml
    coverage.xml
    *,cover
    .hypothesis/
    
    # Translations
    *.mo
    *.pot
    
    # Django stuff:
    *.log
    local_settings.py
    
    # Flask stuff:
    instance/
    .webassets-cache
    
    # Scrapy stuff:
    .scrapy
    
    # Sphinx documentation
    docs/_build/
    
    # PyBuilder
    target/
    
    # IPython Notebook
    .ipynb_checkpoints
    
    # pyenv
    .python-version
    
    # celery beat schedule file
    celerybeat-schedule
    
    
    
    # Spyder project settings
    .spyderproject
    
    # Rope project settings
    .ropeproject
    
    db.sqlite3
```